# Фильтрация значений связанных полей в django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Имеется такой код:
models.py

```
class GoodOptions(models.Model):
    option = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, verbose_name=u'Характеристика', blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Характеристика'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Характеристики'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.option

class OptionValue(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Значение опции', default=u'Значение')
    option = models.ForeignKey('GoodOptions', verbose_name=u'Характеристика', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = (u'Значение характеристики')
        verbose_name_plural = (u'Значения характеристик')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

class OptionsDef(models.Model):
    good = models.ForeignKey('Products', verbose_name=u'Товар', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = models.ForeignKey('GoodOptions', verbose_name=u'Характеристика', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.ForeignKey('OptionValue', verbose_name=u'Значение', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = (u'Значение характеристики товара')
        verbose_name_plural = (u'Значения характеристик товаров')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.option.option
```

forms.py

```
class MyOptionsDefForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OptionsDef
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyOptionsDefForm, self).clean()
        sel_option = cleaned_data.get("option") # получить выбранное из выпадающего списка значение характеристики
        option_id = sel_option.id  # получить id характеристики 
        value = OptionValue.objects.filter(option__optionvalue__option=option_id) # получить отфильтрованные по характеристике значения
        self.value = value
        return self.cleaned_data
```

admin.py

```
from catalog.forms import MyOptionsDefForm
class OptionsDefAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('option', 'good')
    form = MyOptionsDefForm
admin.site.register(OptionsDef, OptionsDefAdmin)
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в админке после выбора из выпадающего списка Характеристики, в выпадающем списке Значений показывались только те, которые принадлежат к данной характеристике. А сейчас у меня выпадают все Значения, вне зависимости от выбранной Характеристики.
Предполагаю решить задачу с помощью переопределении формы в админке и функции def clean - но с текущим кодом админка вообще на нее никак не реагирует.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно под себя переделать следующий код:

```
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
            if db_field.name == "car":
                kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Этот код мою проблему не решает, вместо request.user мне нечего подставить, я не могу получить значение, которое выбрал пользователь в выпадающем списке. Похоже, без js это никак не сделать.

Comment: Тут конечно, в python вы же не можете знать, что выберет польхователь